# Register NPAPI Plugins

Tags: npapi, browser-plugin, dllregistration

i try to register an own NPAPI Plugin, but i dont found informations about that.

**I know** that the NPAPI on Chrome is **deprecated** (i will write a PPAPI Plugin later) but Chrome-Docs says that i must use a `manifest.json` (See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi). But how i register it?

Following i had try:

Over an BATCH-File (**register.bat**):

```
 regsvr32.exe /s "C:\Users\Bizzi\Desktop\WoRPG Plugin\npworpg\Release\npworpg.dll"
 pause
```

Directly in the Registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\
    [worpg.de/WoRPG]
        Description  REG_SZ   World of RPG Browser Plugin
        Path         REG_SZ   C:\Users\Bizzi\Desktop\WoRPG Plugin\npworpg\Release\npworpg.dll
        ProductName  REG_SZ   World of RPG Plug-In
        Vendor       REG_SZ   World of RPG
        Version      REG_SZ   1.0.0

        [MimeTypes]
            [application/x-worpg-launcher]
                Description  REG_SZ   World of RPG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very simple!

Be sure what the depency the browser have. If the browser an 64bit based browser, be sure that the registry entry is set:

Chrome (32bit): `KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\Extensions`

Chrome (64bit): `KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions`

Firefox (32bit): `KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins`

Firefox (64bit): `KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins`

Here is a little **.reg** script:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; MOZILLA 32bit
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@worpg.de/npworpg,version=1.0.0]
"Description"="World of RPG Browser Plugin"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\World of RPG\\plugins\\npworpg.dll"
"ProductName"="npworpg"
"Vendor"="World of RPG"
"Version"="1.0.0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@worpg.de/WoRPG,version=1.0.0\MimeTypes]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@worpg.de/WoRPG,version=1.0.0\MimeTypes\application/x-worpg-launcher]
"Description"="World of RPG"

; MOZILLA 64bit
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@worpg.de/npworpg,version=1.0.0]
"Description"="World of RPG Browser Plugin"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\World of RPG\\plugins\\npworpg.dll"
"ProductName"="npworpg"
"Vendor"="World of RPG"
"Version"="1.0.0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@worpg.de/WoRPG,version=1.0.0\MimeTypes]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@worpg.de/WoRPG,version=1.0.0\MimeTypes\application/x-worpg-launcher]
"Description"="World of RPG"

; CHROME 32bit
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\Extensions\ckpknilfoflolaglllnonhhhnfhaidom]
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\World of RPG\\plugins\\npworpg.dll"
"Version"="1.0.0"

; CHROME 64bit
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions\ckpknilfoflolaglllnonhhhnfhaidom]
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\World of RPG\\plugins\\npworpg.dll"
"Version"="1.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are relatively close, from the looks of things.  The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Plugins/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Plug-in_Development_Overview#Installing_Plug-ins) shows that you have incorrectly formed your [plugin identifier](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/plugins/plugin-identifier.html), however, which should start with a `@`.

Hard to be 100% sure if that's the only issue, but it's the one I see.

```
KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\
[@worpg.de/WoRPG]
```

Try that, see what happens.

Comment: Nope. In the same paths on `MozillaPlugins` are other Plugins registred, with same identifier (for example `@java.com/DTPlugin,version=10.51.2`). I've tried a lot of names (width AND without `@`).

Comment: Are you certain that your plugin is working correctly? If you place it in the Mozilla\plugins directory does it load?  If the DLL doesn't work, it won't show up even if it's installed correctly

Comment: If works in Chrome fine. Only in Firefox the plugin won't load. Tried to reload the plugin-list width `navigator.plugins.refresh();` and/or restarting firefox. Had created an XPI for firefox, installation works but the plugin will be not listen on `about:plugins`

Comment: sounds like there is probably something wrong with your plugin.  You could go look at the registry files for FireBreath, since that's well tested and widely used

Comment: i dont use FireBreath and have some troubles with that (building problems). Had FireBreath tried 1-3 weeks ago